# return Response() has no parameter Django rest framework,like this,what's that mean?

Tags: django-rest-framework

```
@action(detail=True, methods=['post'])
    def operate(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ticket = self.get_object()
        operate_serializer = TicketStateOperateSerializer(request=request,
                                                          ticket=ticket,
                                                          operator=(request.user.username))
        operate_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        data = operate_serializer.data
        data['source'] = request.source
        current_node = data['current_node']
        data['ticket'] = ticket
        (current_node.set_next_action)(operator=request.user.username, **data)
        return Response()
```

This is code, I want to figure it out, this "Response()" represents what

Answer (score 1):

`Response` is imported from:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
```

You can study more about it and its parameters here: [Response](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/)

Depending upon what your function does, you pass the response and status, e-g

```
return Response('Data Saved', status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: sorry  maybe it's my mistake,you didn't understand me , in my code ,that response() represents what mean